# Getting address of location from google map using json instead of Geocoder

Tags: android, json, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am developing an application on Google map.I am new to work on Google map API V2. I want to click on location on map and get address of that location i use Geocoder and it works for me but on different versions of android it will not work so i want to use json anyone help me..
Mainactivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

        lat = point.latitude;
        lng = point.longitude;


         try {
           Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
           List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           if (addresses.size() > 0) {
             Address address = addresses.get(0);

             sb.append(address.getCountryName()).append(", ");
             sb.append(address.getLocality()).append(", ");
             sb.append(address.getSubLocality()).append("\n");
             sb.append(address.getFeatureName()).append(", ");
             sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append(", ");
             sb.append(address.getAdminArea()).append(", ");
             sb.append(address.getPhone()).append("");

           }
           addressString = sb.toString();
           mTapTextView.setText(addressString);

          } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC9yx6mNQGAIQv9GNAPIMXRYaxWhWwMJ2c" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.ShowDirection"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_direction" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what are you use for getting json??

Comment: no idea about json Achilles

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Google GeocodingAPI**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

**Reverse Geocoding** can be acheived by providing the APIKEY, lat and longitude co-ordinates in HTTP GET method ,You can directly get  the result  is in the json response format

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false&key=API_KEY)

Comment: i give API KEY but how i use json method to get address of specific location

Comment: did you provide the lat and lng co-ordinate of the address

Comment: yes i can get the lat and lng by onMapLongclick method but how can i get the address of that location on behalf of providing that lat and lng

Answer (score 0):

Try like below code:

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat+","+lng +"&sensor=true");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

try {
    response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    int b;
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return jsonObject;
}

public static String getLoc(double lat, double lng) {
JSONObject jsonObj = getLocationInfo(lat, lng);
Log.i("JSON string =>", jsonObj.toString());

String currentLocation = "testing";
String street_address = null;
String postal_code = null; 

try {
    String status = jsonObj.getString("status").toString();
    Log.i("status", status);

    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
        JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
        int i = 0;
        Log.i("i", i+ "," + results.length() ); //TODO delete this
        do{

            JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray typesArray = r.getJSONArray("types");
            String types = typesArray.getString(0);

            if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("street_address")){
                street_address = r.getString("formatted_address").split(",")[0];
                Log.i("street_address", street_address);
            }else if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")){
                postal_code = r.getString("formatted_address");
                Log.i("postal_code", postal_code);
            }

            if(street_address!=null && postal_code!=null){
                currentLocation = street_address + "," + postal_code;
                Log.i("Current Location =>", currentLocation); //Delete this
                i = results.length();
            }

            i++;
        }while(i<results.length());

        Log.i("JSON Geo Locatoin =>", currentLocation);
        return currentLocation;
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("testing","Failed to load JSON");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

and access:

```
String currentLocation = getLoc(lat, lng);
```

and add below permissions in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: JSONArray  georesult = json.getJSONArray("results"); give me error on this line

Comment: copy that url and paste in browser and test is it run or not.

Comment: {
   "error_message" : "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: add "&sensor=false" or "=true" to your request

Comment: i change my code.so you can refer it properly..check it now.. and pass your latitude and longitude there

Comment: fatal exception response = client.execute(httpGet); give me error on this also on this line JSONObject jsonObj = getLocationInfo(lat, lng); and also on this String currentLocation = getLoc(lat, lng);

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1131)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)